# Issue when posting empty textarea in array

Tags: arrays, node.js, post, textarea

I've got a dynamic form that can have n amount of rows, so the field names are an array. However I'm running into the problem that when a textarea is empty the value is not submited

[image: Fields]

This causes a discrepancy in the length of the array data (all array's should be 5 long, however only 2 notes where filled in causing the data to slip into the wrong row)

[image: Post Length]

How can I post it so the resulting array for Note is `['','','','Mr Fields','No 543']`?

Here's an example of three of the rows

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="RateId[]" value="23"><input
        type="text" name="Date[]" value="2013.08.23"
        class="datepicker required hasDatepicker" id="dp1378446864655"></td>
    <td>Meeting Room A
        <textarea placeholder="Note" name="Note[]"
            style="height: 26px;"></textarea></td>
    <td class="calc"><input type="number" min="1" name="Count[]"
        style="width: 3em" value="1"> x <input type="hidden"
        name="Nights[]" value="1">
    <div class="pull-right">
            IDR <input type="number" min="1" name="Value[]" value="3000000">
        </div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="RateId[]" value="22"><input
        type="text" name="Date[]" value="2013.08.23"
        class="datepicker required hasDatepicker valid" id="dp1378446864653"></td>
    <td>Airport drop off
        <textarea placeholder="Note" name="Note[]"
            style="height: 26px;">Mr Fields</textarea></td>
    <td class="calc"><input type="number" min="1" name="Count[]"
        style="width: 3em" value="1"> x <input type="hidden"
        name="Nights[]" value="1">
    <div class="pull-right">
            IDR <input type="number" min="1" name="Value[]" value="250000">
        </div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="RateId[]" value="26"><input
        type="text" name="Date[]" value="2013.08.23"
        class="datepicker required hasDatepicker" id="dp1378446864654"></td>
    <td>Restaurant Bill
        <textarea placeholder="Note" name="Note[]"
            style="height: 26px;">No 543</textarea></td>
    <td class="calc"><input type="hidden" name="Count[]" value="1"><input
        type="hidden" name="Nights[]" value="1">
    <div class="pull-right">
            IDR <input type="number" min="1" name="Value[]" value="100">
        </div></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you post your code or logic ?

Comment: @Eez these are some of the dynamic rows being created